# External endpoint of Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dashboard, endpoint

I was just wondering how to manually set the external endpoint used by the Kubernetes web dashboard.

After creating the namespace *kube-system*, I ran the following:

```
kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Is there a flag I can use to specify which tcp port to use for external access? As far as I can tell it's just randomly assigning one. I've looked through the documentation but I'm having a hard time finding a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the desired port as the `nodePort` in the yaml spec that you use to create the service. In this case, where the yaml file you linked to defines the service as:

```
- kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: kubernetes-dashboard
      kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kube-system
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
    selector:
      app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

You would want to define it as below, assuming your desired port number is 33333:

```
- kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: kubernetes-dashboard
      kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kube-system
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 33333
    selector:
      app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: That did it. I noticed that it's strict about the port range. 33333 didn't work, but 315xx did. Is there any documentation giving the total range of allowed nodePort values?

Comment: 30000-32767 by default: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport

Comment: @AlexRobinson where this yaml is located?

Comment: I was just referring to the yaml file linked to in the original question